# how to dropdown combobox automatically in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, drop-down-menu, datagridviewcomboboxcell

how to automatically show dropdown items when users click on a comboBoxCell in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the combo box's GotFocus event, but you'll have to get the combo box instance handle and with it you can do:

```
myComboBox.GotFocus += (s, e) => ((ComboBox)s).DroppedDown = true;
```